# How to view a Javascript file directly from the web, into the Solution?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

How can I open/load a JS file directly from the web, as part of my project in Visual Studio?

This is a sample URL I got from a weather monitoring site:

https://static.eagle.io/85e2aa8e4322e59c8de35847502f1220684b7615/assets/app-public/asset.js

Opening it directly on the browser, just doesn't format the JS nicely (beautify). How can I load and beautify the `asset.js` file in Visual Studio 2022 as part of the project please (not to use it, to view it)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, `asset.js` seems to be minified. Although you could technically format (beautify) the code, it'll still be unreadable. Nonetheless, you could save the file to your computer using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, open it in Visual Studio, and use an extension such as Prettier to format the code.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a direct VS --> File --> Open Web File approach